# Import multiple MySQL stored procedures to PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, sqlyog

Good day, I've uploaded my web-based system to `x10hosting.com` and currently using a free subscription. Lately, I've been importing my exported local `.sql` file that is imported from SQLyog application to PHPmyAdmin.

I have a sample code that is purely modified by me and executes 2 stored procedures.

[image: Sample stored proc code]

I need to import my stored procedures to PHPmyAdmin all at once. But there's an error:

[image: Error]

1 stored proc 'query' at a time is a accepted. I have a total of 40+ of SPs in my `.sql` file and most of it are composed of 300 to 1000+ lines. I don't have time to import or query it one by one.

Here's some info of the version of PHPmyAdmin I'm using:

[image: Version Information]

Comment: You need a delimiter between the two procedures. Try something like `DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE ... END // CREATE PROCEDURE ... END // ...

Comment: "NO SQL" for an UPDATE statement? "MODIFIES SQL DATA" might be more appropriate here.

Comment: +Paul Campbell it's just a sample code, but the essence is to import both SPs on one execution. But thanks, by the way. I think I can use that later.

+Nick some of the forums point out that `DELIMITER` is used if you have super privileges since I'm a free subscriber I don't have the power.

Comment: I hesitate to speak for @Nick, but I think his point is that you need to properly terminate one procedure before you can start another. The BEGIN ... END block in your first procedure doesn't need a semi-colon (or other delimiter e.g. // ) to terminate it but the CREATE PROCEDURE statement does which you have omitted to do. The usual way of telling mysql to treat the statements in a procedure as one unit is to reassign the delimiter. You don't need SUPER privilege to use DELIMITER, you just need access to the mysql cli. Finally, use @ rather than + before names if you want to message someone.

Comment: @PaulCampbell that is exactly my point. Thanks for clarifying.